# Ruby on Rails - Edit Update Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, action

I have a form that I wanna edit some informations, so I drew a get route for our edit form and a update route.

Routes.rb:

```
resource :guide_dog_forms

get '/cao-guia/:id/editar', to: 'guide_dog_forms#edit', as: :edit_guide_dog_form
put '/cao-guia/:id/', to: 'guide_dog_forms#update'
```

After that I edited my controllers, so i added the actions like these:

```
class GuideDogFormsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @contact = GuideDogForm.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.save
      GuideDogMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end

  def edit
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @guidedoguser = GuideDogForm.find(params[:id])
    @guidedoguser.update(name: params[:name], email: params[:email])
    redirect_to guide_dog_form_path(@guidedoguser)
  end

end
```

My current rake routes is like this:

```
guide_dog_forms POST - /guide_dog_forms(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#create
new_guide_dog_forms GET - /guide_dog_forms/new(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#new
edit_guide_dog_forms GET - /guide_dog_forms/edit(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#edit
GET - /guide_dog_forms(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#show
PATCH - /guide_dog_forms(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#update
PUT - /guide_dog_forms(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#update
DELETE - /guide_dog_forms(.:format) - guide_dog_forms#destroy
```

When I submit my edit form, the url rendered is `localhost:3000/guide_dog_forms.80` (80 is the ID of form that I trying edit) and not that which I defined on my routes. Why this is happens? Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a by-product of your `resource` routes.

Try running `rake routes`. You should see the `guide_dog_form_path` route there with the output `/guide_dog_form/:id`, which explains the redirect. You may have to set up another named route and redirect there if you wish to override the behavior of the `resource` method.

Usually you would pass the singular version of the object to `resource`. i.e. `resource :guide_dog_form` or the plural to `resources`. i.e. `resources :guide_dog_forms`

Based on the code you've provided, I imagine your intent is:
`resources :guide_dog_forms`

*FWIW, as of Rails 4 it's customary to use the `PATCH` verb instead of `PUT` to update records.

Comment: How canI override the behavior of the resource method? Oh, I update my question with my current rake routes.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have `resource :guide_dog_forms` instead of `resource :guide_dog_form`. You can override any resource route by placing a matching route above it in the routes file

Comment: Even making these changes, the processed URL remains `localhost:3000/guide_dog_forms.80`. I dont know what it can be :/

Comment: It's because you're using the resource route helper.

Comment: I got it following your instructions. Thanks!